# Display Image before click on upload javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, imageview

I am trying to implement a message functionality. In this the user is allowed to upload an image. My upload function is working fine. But i want to the preview of the image that the user wants to upload before he actually clicks the submit button. My working code for image input so far is
`<input name="attach" type="file" id="attach" />`
I have searched a lot and have reached a conclusion that i will have to use java-script or j-query for this i created a `onchange="readURL(this);"` function and placed it in `input`. I also created an image tag in which the image will be displayed `<img id="preview_img" style="max-width: 130px; max-height: 130px; display: none" src=""/>` From here on i am confused. How will i change the image `src` with java-script or what value will i change it to?

Answer (score 0):

you can put this in some jQuery event ( 'click' , 'load', not sure when you want this to happen):

$('#preview_img').attr('src', '...');

Comment: Actually I want to know what value should i put in `src` @sixstarpro

Answer (score 0):

Set the [data URI](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) with the image content to the `src` attribute. As long as you don't have the image uploaded on the server, you can load its content content in the data URI format by [FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL) in your `readURL`, where you have access to the selected file either via `event.target.files` or via the `this` which you send there in your code.

Have a look at [an answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22112881/623816); it accesses the `input` element by its ID, but you can easily adapt it to consume the element you send to the `readURL`.