# Display Image Using Upload JS

Tags: javascript

I want to display the image using the upload form and submit button.

But the problem though, I can't make the image appear.

Here's what I did.

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myFile").value;
document.getElementById('myImg').src = document.getElementById("myFile").name;

<form>Select a file to upload:
<input type="file" id="myFile" name=filename>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Upload This</button>
<img id="myImg" src="">
```

I just don't know what seems to be the problem with this.

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

The browser does NOT allow javascript full access to the `.value` property of an input tag with `type="file"`.  This is for security reasons so no local path information is made available to javascript.

Thus, you can't set a `.src` value on an image tag based on a file input value that the end-user specified.

Comment: You could read the image with a javascript file reader and display it using a canvas object. Not sure about browser compatibility though, cause it requires some html5 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upload the image to server side, you have a possibility to do it only in the client side.

add a div to your html (dom):

```
<div id='bottom'>
    <div id='drag-image' class='holder-file-uploader bottom-asset'> Drag here an image</div>
</div>
```

add this javascript:

```
<script>
    var holder = document.getElementById('drag-image');

    holder.ondragover = function () { return false; };
    holder.ondragend = function () { return false; };
    holder.ondrop = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();     
        //do something with:
        var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
        console.log(files);

        bottomFileAdd(files, 0);
        return false;
   };

//Recursive function to add files in the bottom div
//this code was adapted from another code, i didn't test it
var bottomFileAdd = function (files, i) {
    if(!i) i=0;
    if (!files || files.length>=i) return;

    var file = files.item(i);
    var img = document.createElement('img');

    var bottom = document.getElementById('bottom'); //this string should not be static
    bottom.appendChild(img);    

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        console.log(event.target);
        img.src =  event.target.result;
        bottomFileAdd(files, i+1);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
</script>
```

note: It may not work in older browsers.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to set the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag to a local file path.  However, the web browser doesn't expose the local file URL (`file://...`) in the `value` property of the `<input>` tag.  The browser implementation may vary; Chrome, for example, gives you a fake path.

You can load the image by the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API into a [data URI](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) and show it by setting the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag:

```
function myFunction() {
  var myFile = document.getElementById("myFile");
  if (myFile.files && myFile.files.length) {
    if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = event.target.result;
      };
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(myFile.files[0]);
    } else {
      alert("Your browser doesn't support the FileReader API.")
    }
  } else {
    alert("No file was selected.")
  }
}
```

You need a fairly modern web browser for this to work:

```
 Browser  Firefox  Chrome  IE  Opera  Safari
 Version  3.6      7       10  12.02  6.0.2
```

You can have a look at [a working sample page](http://jsfiddle.net/prantlf/FsG3m/).  The final implementation of such image preview should set the `<img>` element to a fixed size, but your markup with my function is enough as a simple demonstration.